# Fixing System.Object[] in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have a script that will ping a list of offline workstations, then if the workstation is offline query SCCM for the description. It then takes both the workstation ID and the description and puts that in a body of an email and sends it to a specific address.

The script works great inside PowerShell as long as I only output the variable. If I use the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet the only thing that shows up in the body of the email is `System.Object[]`.

How can I go about fixing this? I have read about the `-join` attribute but I am not quite sure where to add this to my script.

```bsh
$list = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\workstations.txt"

foreach ($workstation in $list) {
    $test = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $workstation -Quiet
    $WQLquery = @"
select SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Description from
SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_SYSTEM on
SMS_G_System_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId inner join 
SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM on 
SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_SYSTEM.Name = '$workstation'
"@

    $description = Get-WmiObject -Query $WQLquery -ComputerName 'WORKSTATIONHERE' -Namespace 'root\sms\SITEHERE' |
                   Select-Object  Description
    if ($test -match "false") {
        $offlinelist += ,@("$workstation", $description)
    }
}

$offlinelist
Send-MailMessage -To "TOTHEUSER" -From "FROM" -Subject "Offline Workstations" -SmtpServer "SMTPHERE" -Body "<p>These workstations are offline: </p> $offlinelist" -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build a array of (custom) objects and put the variable with that array in a string, PowerShell will expand it to the string representation of an object array, which is `System.Object[]`.

What you actually want there is an HTML table of the workstation IDs and descriptions (since you're sending the mail as HTML anyway.

```bsh
$offlinelist = foreach ($workstation in $list) {
    ...
    if ($test -match "false") {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            ID          = $workstation
            Description = $description
        })
    }
}

$body = $offlinelist |
        ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent '<p>These workstations are offline:</p>' |
        Out-String
Send-MailMessage ... -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: This is looking a lot better than my code. When I run this it returns an error:


`Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified 
method is not supported.`

However, if I just use the `write-host` cmdlet to display the `$body` variable in ISE it shows that it is generating the HTML and the displaying the custom objects correctly. How do I get this to convert `System.Object[]` over to a string?

Comment: Ah, yes. `ConvertTo-Html` still produces an array. You need an `Out-String` too. See updated answer.

Comment: You sir, have saved me a huge headache. I was beginning to think I would have to deal with exporting the results to a `.csv and sending it as an attachment. I am fairly new to PS and custom objects have been a foreign concept to me. It looks like I need to start using them more often!